# Web Automation Testing ~ Trying to append to an existing string in a textfield

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems, watir, watir-webdriver

Hi I am writing an automation test script using Watir. I was trying to append a string to an existing string within a text field. I was able to figure out how to append to the end of the text field with this line of code:

```
browser.text_field(:id => "custom-preview-text").append "Hello World"
```

How can I change this line so I append this text after a specific string inside the text field?

Comment: You could give one up vote also us? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achive this :

```
  require 'watir-webdriver'
  b = Watir::Browser.new
  b.goto 'https://www.google.co.in/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=gdg&btnK='
  elem = b.text_field(:id => "gbqfq")
  val = elem.value
  elem.clear
  elem.send_keys val + "Good bye!"
  puts elem.value
  # >> gdgGood bye!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the text after a specific string, I think you will have to get the string of the text field, use Ruby to determine the new string, and then input the text field with the new string.

You can use `gsub` to insert text before or after a certain part of the string. For example:

```
original_text = 'word1 word2 word3'

# Insert text before word2
p original_text.sub(/(?=word2)/, 'insertion ')
#=> "word1 insertion word2 word3"

# Insert text after word2
p original_text.sub(/(?<=word2)/, ' insertion')
#=> "word1 word2 insertion word3"
```

Inserting the new string within the text field would look like:

```
# Get the current text field value
text_field = browser.text_field
original_text = text_field.text

# If you want to insert before word 2
new_text = original_text.sub(/(?=word2)/, 'insertion ')
# If you want to insert after word 2
new_text = original_text.sub(/(?<=word2)/, ' insertion')

# Set the text field with the new value
text_field.set(new_text)
```

Note that this solution assumes that you do not mind re-inputting the existing text (ie there is no javascript that would fire and mess up your test).